# How to export pyreadstat’s metadata container to json

Tags: python, pandas, spss

I read a sav file using this code:

`df_file, meta_data = pyreadstat.read_sav(‘path’)`

It returns `df_file` as pandas DataFrame but returns `meta_data` as `metadata_container object`. I need to share `meta_data` object to a colleague who is not programmer. How do I export it? I can easily export `df_file` because it is a DataFrame but can’t export `meta_data` to something like JSON because it is not a DataFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not perfect but it's a first step, you can use `meta.__dict__`

```
import json

df, meta = pyreadstat.read_sav('path')

json.dump(meta.__dict__, open("metadata.json", "w"), indent=4)
```